# Does the credit card used to pay or the address on the registration matter for who owns a domain name?

Tags: web-hosting

I am thinking about asking my friend to help me buy a domain name in another country using his credit card as I don't have one in that country. I still have a house in that country where I come from. So, I will use that address for every other information for domain registration.

If I use his credit card to pay for the website, does he become the default owner of the website?

Are you guys aware of any precedents regarding this?

Comment: Possession is 9/10ths of the law.

Comment: What do you mean by possession?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_is_nine-tenths_of_the_law

Comment: @JohnConde Gun caliber is the other 1/10th. Try it if you doubt me. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "owner" of a *domain* is whoever's name/organisation/address details have been entered as the legal *registrant*. The method of payment used to register that domain should be irrelevant (unless there is some quirky ruling by the TLDs register?!).

You mention "website" 3 times and "domain" only once, but I assume you are referring to the "domain" in all cases?!